# Android: What activity lifecycle method to clean cache in app?

Tags: android, caching

I'm storing my images in subdirectories under the cache directory. I have a cache cleaning task I want to run, that checks the size of the cache and deletes files if necessary (according to some rules I've set up). My question is, what's the best time to run this? I was thinking in one of the Activity lifecycle methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: just curious, why do you need to clear the cache? the OS will do it automatically if it needs to, so why bother?

Comment: He's talking about the file cache. The OS only does it when it absolutely has to, you should clean your cache when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Yes, Falmarri is correct. I have TONS of photos I'm loading into the app, which I store in the file cache. I don't want the app growing too large in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @binnyb said, OS will automatically clear the cache.

However, if what you call as cache is not the cache of OS (eg. You trying to store some data internal to application), then I suggest, do the check at onPause() or onResume() methods. I will not rely on onDestroy of a service.

Comment: I'm talking about the app's internal file cache. onResume seems to work good, because it is getting hit when I jump back into the parent Activity of the one that is savings a bunch of cached images to disk. I just spawn a cleanup thread in there, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably fire off a `Service` with a separate thread to do this in the `onDestroy()` of key activities, maybe keeping track of a last-clean-started time in the service to make sure the hard work is only done every few minutes. onDestroy() isn't *guaranteed* to be called for every kind of Activity termination, but it reliably is during normal activity destruction due to backing out of an Activity, for example. Just make sure anything it does that touches the disk happens outside the UI thread.